# Twitter link on https

Tags: asp.net, twitter, https

I want to put twitter link on https link. it gives me error/not display twitter count button perfectly.

- http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js  -work perfect
- https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js -not working.

Answer (score 1):

From [Twitter dev FAQ](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#https)

> At the moment the Tweet Button does
>   not work over SSL. We are looking into
>   making this possible but for the time
>   being we only support HTTP. If you
>   need to use SSL we recommend you build
>   your own Tweet Button.

Comment: thank for your answer. but will you help me how to create own tweet button?

Comment: can we get twitter count on costume tweet button on https?